# IP compatible with localhost and external

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, ip, wide-area-network

Im working on an online game, but I'm having an annoying issue with me and my friend testing. The thing is, I set the client to connect to my WAN IP so he can connect, but then I cannot connect as it only work with localhost or 127.0.0.1. If I set it to localhost, obviously he cannot connect.

I also tried using a DNS server, which used to work but recently I set it up again and it's not working.

Any ideas on how I can get a single domain or IP that works for a local connection and a WAN connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an entry to your hosts file.

In your hosts you can write: **127.0.0.1 thegame**

and your friend can write: **[your wan ip] thegame**

Then you can both connect to thegame.

Comment: Wow thanks, I'm pretty sure this is what I did last time when it was working and forgot to add it after I formatted my PC. Thanks again